# Cannot run program "adb": error=13, Permission denied

Tags: java, android, kotlin, adb

I have a program, which must execute only one command

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb shell input tap 0 0")
    }
}
```

But I'm getting an error

```
Process: com.example.tomfo.pokerclicker, PID: 11578
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "adb": error=13, Permission denied
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1050)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:695)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:525)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:422)
    at com.example.tomfo.pokerclicker.MainActivity$onCreate$1.run(MainActivity.kt:14)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:562)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:512)
 Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:133)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:132)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:695) 
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:525) 
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:422) 
    at com.example.tomfo.pokerclicker.MainActivity$onCreate$1.run(MainActivity.kt:14) 
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:562) 
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:512)
```

Although I've added adb to path into properties on Windows and can run abd commands throw Android Studio console (but in Android Studio console command is not green). How to solve this problem? This command is working throw Studio console command

Comment: From where are you executing this code? From an emulator or from your device?

Comment: From my emulator

Comment: Have you put `adb root` and restart the emulator? And then `adb -e shell`?

Comment: Yep, it's not worked

Comment: Do you have `x` permission on that `adb`?

Comment: @Strangelove any solution? because I am also getting java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "adb": error=13, Permission denied

Comment: Still not. I've threw it after several attempts

Answer (score 15):

adb is a tool you use on your computer, "adb shell" opens a shell on the device (or emulator), and "adb shell command" runs the command on it.

So if you want to run the command programmatically on the device, just remove "adb shell":

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("input tap 0 0")
```

Comment: @ Cédric LE MOING I followed your answer for the command `adb shell wm overscan", "0,0,0,-220` but the only thing it did was stop the message of exception of error no 13 from coming, it didn't execute anything

Answer (score 1):

I got it like this

```
 fun commandAdb() {
    InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().uiAutomation.executeShellCommand("svc wifi disable")
    InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().uiAutomation.executeShellCommand("svc data disable")
}
```

Comment: Is it still working? Because Android Studio gives me import error of InstrumentationRegistry and executeShellCommand seems not to be visible in IDE's prompt...

Comment: Thank you. I was able to use your answer to turn on location services for testing location. // turn on location services
    InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation()
        .uiAutomation
        .executeShellCommand("settings put secure location_mode 3")
    // force refresh
    InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation()
        .uiAutomation
        .executeShellCommand("settings get secure location_mode")